# No of VM Queues is based on the no of request or only based on the name of vm queue

Tags: queue, virtual-machine, mule

I have a flow which is redirectiong to 3 different flows asynchronously. I have set some session variables in the intial flow, which i want to use in this 3 different flows further, with some same names. To avoid overriding of the values i have used a vm tranport for each of the 3 flows (one way). I didn't get any other options instead of using a vm queue transport for my requirement as it is asynchronous also.

Now i have doubts, how vm many vm queues will be created if i have more than 1 request coming, if suppose 3 separate request are coming for initial flow, will mule create 9 vm queues or maximum only 3 vm queues will be created. Could someone please clarify this. Also How and when vm queues are created and destroyed in mule. How much memory of JVM it takes, can i control this creation, destruction and size in memory of vm queue.

Also can there some other approach, to change the mule message while passing between two flows instead of using a transport ?

Still I didn't have any answer for this question. If i am not defining the VM queue size, will it decrease its size when the messages are read from the vm queue ??

Answer (score 0):

Each VM queue name corresponds to one queue, so you would get three queues, each of which receive three messages. The Queues are created and destroyed when Mule starts/stops, but you can also manage them programmatically, like anything else in the Mule context.

You can change the properties of Mule messages in a number of ways, so you would probably not need to "clean up" the properties by sending the message through a transport. See this for a comprehensive explanation: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-school-the-mulemessage-property-scopes-and-variables/

UPDATE:

To see your current vm queue size in a Mule app, see this post: [Number of Messages in Mule ESB VM inbound endpoint Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775070/number-of-messages-in-mule-esb-vm-inbound-endpoint-queue)

If you just want to attach some properties to a specific message before sending it to another flow, you can do this with `<set-property propertyName="myprop" value="myval"/>` and retrieve with `#[message.outboundProperties['myprop']]` in the other flow(s).

How about the size increment or decrement when we are not defining the max size.

Comment: Thanks Anton for the reply, i am using vm queue only, so that my mule context get separated from the mule context of intial first flow. But if i directly use async flow-ref, my mule context will be same and the variables will be over ridden, if am doing any changes in intial flow.

Comment: Also, i need to know that how much size vm queue takes in memory and if it is default, will it be always there for all time until my mule server stops. Also, will it be destroyed if there are no messages or it will exist incase of no messages also. One more question can i use some transport rather than vm queue such as http , etc, which is more prefferable to use instead of queue

Comment: The vm queue is just simple a mechanism to temporarily keep your messages in the memory while they are being taken to the next processor. The mechanism is on while your Mule is running. The memory it takes up is mostly the space to keep the messages that are going through it at that point of time. You should not need to worry about the performance, but you can control the max number of enqueued messages with maxOutstandingMessages attribute. If you really want to use some transport internally, use vm, but I suggest you look at the link in my answer and learn to configure the variables.

Comment: Thanks Anton, i have looked into the link, i am implementing transport between the intial flow and next 3 flows is because i want to create a separate mule message for next 3 flows. So that i can use the scoped variables further flows and in the initial flows separately. It will override the values in all the threads if i dont use a transport. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong, or i can achieve this by using some other approach rather than a transport

Comment: Also i need to know, if the message is read by the next flow, will the vm clears out the memory space automatically. Do it behave like a arraylist in java ?. Also is ther any default size of vm queue. Can i test to see the size of my vm queue in my mule project ? VM queues are created in JVM memory space ? Please share some links if you have regarding vm queue with details for more understanding.

Comment: I understand about the scopes of Variables but it is not solving my issues here. My concern is if i call a 2nd flow async from first flow and the values in the variables which are set in 1st flow, are changed in further code in 1st flow, it will be changed automatically in 2nd flow also, which i don't want. That's y i m using a transport. But I have concern about whcih transport to be used and how vm transport is going to behave, when multiple request hits my application